# Can't get in to edit Fstab and Crypttab. Veracrypt container hanging up system on load attempt

Tags: boot, xubuntu, gparted, veracrypt

I have Xubuntu on my laptop with full disk encryption. One hard drive.

I installed Veracrypt on it a few days ago, but wanted it to autoload the encrypted file container I created. I searched online and found a site that said this:

"You merely need to add a single line (per volume you wish to auto-mount) to your crypttab file. The general format is:

volume_name /path/to/volume password tcrypt-veracrypt,tcrypt-keyfile=/path/to/keyfile

1. The volume name is one you make up. (It gets added to /dev/mapper/ – and you’ll use that fact in a minute.)
2. The path to your volume can either be a file (/home/user/encrypted.volume) or a block device (/dev/sdx1) or a UUID.
3. The password can be set as none – meaning the user will need to provide it at boot (only once, still better than at every login). Alternatively, it can be a path to a file containing only the password. If you aren’t using a password and are only using one or more keyfiles – then set the password to /dev/null
4. Since this is a VeraCrypt volume you’re auto-mounting, you need to mark it as such with the tcrypt-veracrypt option. If you’re using a keyfile, then you need to specify that and it’s location tcrypt-keyfile=/path/to/keyfile(If you’re not using keyfiles, then be sure not to copy-paste the option in… and delete the unnecessary comma, too!)

At this point, the encrypted volume will be auto-unencrypted at startup. Half the job is done. Now you just need to auto-mount it.

You’ll update your fstab: /etc/fstab with a single line per volume. The general format will look like this:

/dev/mapper/volume_name /mnt/point auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0

1. Remember that volume_name you chose earlier? Here’s another place to use it.
2. The mount point can be anywhere you’d like.
3. You can specify the filesystem type or leave it as auto.
4. The rest of the options shown here just ensures others can read and write to the mounted volume."

It all seemed simple enough. I added the one line at the bottom of each file. Fairly certain I made the mount point the home directory. Then I rebooted.

It asks me for the full disk encryption password on every reboot. No problem there. Enter it and booting continues.

Gets to the line where it says: OK Started LSB : Apparmor initialization
and then stalls with:
A start job is running for dev-map...mycontainer.device (minutes seconds / no limit)

It hangs there forever apparently. I guess it is trying to do the autoload of mycontainer, but it doesn't ask for a password. It just hangs with the timer ticking up.

I have tried and tried to get access to the fstab and crypttab files, but since the drive is not mounted when it hangs, there is no access to the files.

I tried the live CD version of Ubuntu, Puppy, Slax trying to see if I could somehow get access in some way. No luck so far.

At one point I was able to use Gparted and mount the drive using my full disk encryption password. But it still would not let me access the files.

Is my only option a disk wipe and start over? I would really like to save the Home directory files if at all possible.

I also tried to install Ubuntu from the live CD, figuring it may give me the option to save the home directory, but it doesn't even recognize that anything is on the disk and just wants to wipe everything. So I just exit out.

Very frustrating.

Comment: Just fishing here, but...these instructions you are citing are for cryptsetup, not VeraCrypt, right? At least it looks like it. In the crypttab file, have you entered "password" like it was suggested or did you enter "none"? Because it only asks for the password if you enter "none", otherwise it will interpret "password" as the passphrase, which is probably not correct, so it will not decrypt. In order to correct your crypttab you will have to boot into a recovery session and edit them from there.

Comment: This is the site I got the code from: https://www.computercorrect.com/2018/operating-systems/linux/ubuntu/auto-mounting-a-veracrypt-volume-under-ubuntu-debian-linux/

Comment: Like I said, it looks like those are instructions to use dm-crypt/cryptsetup to mount a VeraCrypt container. Verify that your crypttab is set up correctly as I explained above.

Comment: I can get to the grub menu and choose advanced options. But when I choose recovery mode it just goes through the same process and winds up at the line with the timer ticking away. I have tried rebooting and holding the shift key down, but it doesn't bring up anything different.

Comment: Well, from your description it is not clear what you tried to mount where, and which files you edited. So if recovery mode does not work, your only other option is to boot into a live session from a USB stick, and repair the files from there.

Comment: Using a Debian live disk I was able to access the fstab and crypttab files and delete the two lines I had added. Debian has better recovery options than most of the other live distros I tried. So that problem was resolved. I thought my Xubuntu hard disk install would boot up like normal at this point. Well, sort of. The problem is now, it gets me all the way to the user logon screen, except I am no longer listed as a user. It only shows Guest or other. Not sure why. Tried reinstalling Xubuntu to see if it would recognize the prior install but it does not.

Comment: So I aborted the reinstall. When I tried mounting the encrypted drive, it asks me for the passphrase as normal, but then says I can't mount it because of some permission issue and then apparently mounts it anyway. So I made progress, but still can't get to my files because my logon has disappeared. When I click on the encrypted drive it will bring up the files, but my home folder has an "x" on it and a few of the other folders too. Sill no access. My logon name disappeared and I don't know why. Something got lost along the way.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your user actually disappeared? The fact it isn't presented on the logon screen may not necessarily mean it doesn't exist. There should be an option like "Other" on logon. Have you tried entering your username manually?

Comment: Yes. The two options it gives me are "Guest Session" and "Other." It says incorrect password when I use "other" and type in my username and password. I know it is the correct password. When I try the Guest session, the screen just goes blank and then brings me back to the logon screen.

Comment: Strangely all the usual power off options in the drop down menu are grayed out as well. I have to hold the power button down to shut down.

Comment: Trying to enter my username manually does not work either.

Comment: It would seem like something is seriously broken in your installation. Only recommendation I can give is trying to access the encrypted container/partition from a separate live OS and recover the data on it. Unless the container's header is somehow broken, it should always be possible to get access as root user.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it's a lost cause. One of the big drawbacks to using disk encryption it seems. My command line knowledge is very limited. I will try Debian again to see if I can get it to access my hard drive files again. Last time it showed an "X" on the home directory and some other files. But I couldn't do anything further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I will try and summarize.

1. I tried the Debian live disk again, but made no headway.
2. Then I put in the install disk for Xubuntu and chose the "try" option. I didn't want to overwrite anything with an actual install.
3. Was able to decrypt the hard drive as before. The usual access permission errors popped up.
4. I had no internet connected, nor was I going to attempt a connection to the laptop at this point. I used my other computer to research more online.
5. I decided to try the "sudo chmod -R -v 777 *" code on the hard drive to release all file permission restrictions on everything. Major security warnings from people, but I had nothing to lose at this point. I needed to make headway somewhere.
6. "Sudo -s" to get the root prompt.
7. My user home folder was showing a "..private.." file name and a text file. I used "nano (textfile)" to view it. It said, I needed to use "ecryptfs-mount-private" to get into the file, which was my Home folder.
8. Tried, but got error...‘/run/user/999/gvfs’: Permission denied
9. More Google time. Ran the following in terminal..."umount /run/user/999/gvfs"
10. Then ran "ecryptfs-recovery-private"
11. It asked me if I knew my user login password. Yes. Typed that in.
12. It asked me again after kicking back some results. Typed it in again.
    If you don't know the logon password, I think it will then ask if you know the encryption passphrase. That long code the installer tells you to write down when you initially install the Linux distribution....and keep in a safe place.
13. Success! It decrypted the Home folder and mounted it. I had access finally!!
14. I moved all the Home files to a new folder on my portable hard drive. I checked to make sure I could open them, and I indeed could.

I wasn't sure if I should move any of the other system folders besides the home folder.

So it was just research luck on my part that I landed on the right combination of things today. I had some usual terminal window rookie issues, but figured it out eventually.

"df -h" was helpful in figuring out what I needed to input in the terminal window. And of course, "ls", "nano", and "mv" were helpful as well.

I am going to wipe the hard drive on the laptop and re-install Xubuntu. And from now on, I'm not going to mess with adding code to files trying to get Veracrypt to auto load. That mistake sent me down the rabbit hole for more than a month. Lesson learned.

Comment: Not sure why you had to mess with ecryptfs when you said you used a Veracrypt container, but glad you figured it out.

Comment: My explanation was not as clear as it should have been. The presence of an empty Veracrypt container was not the issue. It was when I modified the Fstab and Crypttab files in order to get Veracrypt to auto load during boot up. Doing so caused the big problem. System hung. I deleted the modified lines, but then my logon disappeared and I needed access to my Home files. So that became the ultimate issue at hand. And since the entire disc was encrypted when I installed Xubuntu, it wasn't just a simple matter of landing on the Home directory and clicking on it. Glad I finally found a work around.